# Kendo UI Grid add link

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want data in my column to be link to another page.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
columns
    .Bound(p => p.Name)
    .Title("Name")
    .ClientTemplate("<a href='external/page/url'>#:Name#</a>")
```

[Docs for `ClientTemplate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#clienttemplate).

You also mix it with [`Html.ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
.ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("#:Name#"))
```

To change the action and/or the controller, add the 2nd and 3rd params to it:

```
.ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("#:Name#", "Action", "Controller"))
```

If you wanna pass any data through the url, use the route parameters as the 4th param:

```
.ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("#:Name#", "Action", "Controller", new { id = p.Id }))
```

The `ActionLink` helper will produce a link the as the string I proposed above, with the text being `#:Name` which is what the template will understand as the your `Name` property in the row.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

```
   column.Template(p => @Html.ActionLink("Title", "Method", "Controller", new { id = p.propId, }));
```

More details: http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-mvc-grid-actionlink-column